# How can I make it so this creates a second random number in a second textbox

Tags: html

**I don't know how to make this so it generates two different numbers and puts it into two different text boxes I have tried a lot but I just cant get it**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Dice Game</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body,input{font-family:sans-serif; color:#FF0000; background-color:#990000#000000; }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript"language="javascript">
 function roller(){
 var num=Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
 document.myForm.output.value=num;
 }

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form id="myForm" name="myForm"method="post"action="">
 <input type="button" name="Roll" id="Roll" value="Button" onclick="roller()"/>

 <br/>

 <input type="text" name="output" size="16" disabled="disabled" id="output"/>

 <form id="myForm" name="myForm"method="post"action="">

 <br/>

 <input type="text" name="output" size="16" disabled="disabled" id="output"/>




 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is much longer than it needs to be. I cleaned it up and put it in a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HxzcC/

HTML:

```
<button id="roll" onclick="roller()">Roll</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="input1" size="16" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" id="input2" size="16" disabled="disabled" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function roller(){
    var num = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
    document.getElementById('input1').value = num;
    var num = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
    document.getElementById('input2').value = num;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please mark my post as 'best answer' for future users.